# New York Water Quality-What to do with 85% data missing

Tags: r, filter, null, missing-data

I'm using the [New York City Water Quality dataset](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Environment/Drinking-Water-Quality-Distribution-Monitoring-Dat/bkwf-xfky) to conduct some analysis. However, I found out 103160 out of 118674 rows in this dataset has an empty *Fluoride* value.[image: Fluoride column] And all those rows with missing values are unique.

Should I keep those data, or should I assume those are supposed to be 0?
Thanks[image: DataFrame]

Answer (score 2):

The available data is consistently 0.6-0.8, with few values near zero. It looks very much like those are missing and not actually zeroes. The [HHS recommends 0.7 mg/L,](https://nccd.cdc.gov/doh_mwf/default/AboutMWF.aspx#:%7E:text=The%20U.S.%20Department%20of%20Health,and%20promotes%20good%20oral%20health.) so it would probably be a big scandal we'd hear about if NYC was actually unfluorinated >80% of the time.

```
library(tidyverse)
water %>% 
  ggplot(aes('Fluoride (mg/L)')) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]

```
water %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::mdy(`Sample Date`)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date,`Fluoride (mg/L)`)) +
  geom_jitter(size = 0.1)
```

[image]